# How to merge two array of object into one array of object based on key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, destructure

i'm trying to merge two array of object based on key. two array of object like this,

```
    let array1 = [
    {
      name: "Deepak",
      age: 20
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 30
    }
    ]
```

```
    let array2 = [
    {
      name: "Deepak",
      favGame: "Cricket"
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      favGame: "Football"
    },
    {
      name: "Kailash",
      favGame: "Basketball"
    }
   ]
```

I found difficulties to merge as expected format. I expecting format like this

```
   let finalArray = [
    {
        name: "Deepak",
        age: 20,
        favGame: "Cricket"
      },
      {
        name: "John",
        age: 30,
        favGame: "Football"
      },
      {
        name: "Kailash",
        favGame: "Basketball"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array.map()` and `Array.find()` can do it

```js
let array1 = [
    {
      name: "Deepak",
      age: 20
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 30
    }
    ]

let array2 = [
    {
      name: "Deepak",
      favGame: "Cricket"
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      favGame: "Football"
    },
    {
      name: "Kailash",
      favGame: "Basketball"
    }
   ]
   
let result = array2.map(a => {
   let obj = array1.find(i => i.name === a.name)
   if(obj){
    a.age = obj.age
   }
   return a
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a1 = [ { name: 'Deepak', age: 20 }, { name: 'John', age: 30 } ]
let a2 = [
  { name: 'Deepak', favGame: 'Cricket' },
  { name: 'John', favGame: 'Football' },
  { name: 'Kailash', favGame: 'Basketball' }
]

console.log(Object.values([...a1, ...a2]
  .reduce((a,{name, ...p})=>(a[name]={...a[name]??{},name,...p},a), {})))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const array1 = [
  {
   name: "Deepak",
   age: 20
  },
  {
   name: "John",
   age: 30
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
   name: "Deepak",
   favGame: "Cricket"
  },
  {
   name: "John",
   favGame: "Football"
  },
  {
   name: "Kailash",
   favGame: "Basketball"
  }
];

const mergedArray = [...array1, ...array2];
const newArray = [];
mergedArray.forEach((item) => {
  const key = item.name;
  let index = -1;
  newArray.forEach((newArrayItem, _index) => {
    if(newArrayItem.name === key)
    index = _index;
  });
  if(index === -1){
    newArray.push({});
    index = newArray.length - 1;
  }
  newArray[index]["name"] = item.name;
  if(item.age) {
    newArray[index]["age"] = item.age;
  }
  if(item.favGame) {
    newArray[index]["favGame"] = item.favGame;
  }
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the items by `name`.

This will create an object with a property for each `name` we can then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to return the result as an array.

Since we're using a mapping object, this approach will be efficient for large arrays.

```js
let array1 = [ { name: "Deepak", age: 20 }, { name: "John", age: 30 } ]
let array2 = [ { name: "Deepak", favGame: "Cricket" }, { name: "John", favGame: "Football" }, { name: "Kailash", favGame: "Basketball" } ]
   
const result = Object.values([...array1, ...array2].reduce((acc, { name, ...obj }) => { 
    acc[name] = { ...(acc[name] || {}), name, ...obj };
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```